# Invalid cast from Complex* to double

Tags: c++, casting, double

I have to return the distance between two complex numbers and the error I get is in the return line saying "Invalid cast from Complex* to double".

```
double Complex::distance(const Complex &a, const Complex &b)
{
    Complex *number = new Complex();

    number->modificaRe(a.real() - b.real());
    number->modificaIm(a.imag() - b.imag());

    return (double)number;
}
```

Could you please tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong? 
Not to mention that the teacher gave us the definition of this function as "static double" but I was getting another error so I just removed "static".

Comment: Your aware that C++ has a complex type in the [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)?

Comment: Because if I don't do so the xCode says: Conversion from 'Complex*' to non-scalar type 'Complex' requested. It's the first day I write C++ [forgot to mention, don't be harsh on me]

Comment: I think you are supposed to take the *absolute value* of your `number`, AFAIK - this is how distance is defined.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg But it is clearly HW assignment, which asks for creating such class, nothing wrong in "reinventing the wheel" for educational purposes, no point to use built in libraries for these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly the distance can be calculated using pythagorus - so creating the 
Complex object in distance() is not necessary.

```
double Complex::distance(const Complex &a, const Complex &b)
{    
    double x = a.real() - b.real();
    double y = a.imag() - b.imag();

    return sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a double cannot carry both the real and imaginary parts of the Complex.

I believe that the distance between two complex numbers is the sqrt of the sum of the square of the differences.

So, you code should be...

```
double Complex::distance(const Complex &a, const Complex &b)
{
  double number;

  double r = a.real() - b.real();
  double i = a.imag() - b.imag();

  number = sqrt(r*r + i*i);

  return number;
}
```

As H2CO3 points out it may be safter to use std::hypot...so

```
double Complex::distance(const Complex &a, const Complex &b)
{
  return std::hypot(a.real() - b.real(), a.imag() - b.imag());
}
```

Comment: Instead of `sqrt(r*r + i*i)`, use `std::hypot(r, i)`.

Comment: I don't know what to say, from what I've learned the distance is: |z1-z2| [..]

Comment: @Teodora - Right, that is correct, and if you wanted your distance as a Complex number that is what you would do. But, since you asked for distance as a scalar, you have to use the Pythagorean theorem (x*x + y*y = z*z) and solve for Z. It doesn't make any difference if the 2 dimension are X/Y or Real/Imaginary, Pythagorus was still right.

Comment: "hypot is not a member of std"

Comment: Use `#include <cmath>`. See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/hypot

Comment: @H2CO3 better still, use the `std::complex` class template and supported operations.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to use the standard library's [`std::comlpex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) class template. You can use subtraction and `std::abs` to get the "distance":

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T complex_distance(const std::complex<T>& a, const std::complex<T>& b)
{
  return std::abs(b-a);
}

int main()
{
  std::complex<double> c1(-1,-1);
  std::complex<double> c2(2,2);
  std::cout << (c2-c1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << complex_distance(c2,c1) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting from a pointer to a `Complex` to a `double` is not supported. It's not even clear why you're creating a pointer here rather than just allocating it on the stack.

For example:

```
double Complex::distance(const Complex &a, const Complex &b)
{
    Complex number;

    number.modificaRe(a.real() - b.real());
    number.modificaIm(a.imag() - b.imag());

    return (double)number;
}
```